# What determines the level of spells a Ritual Caster can copy into the ritual spell book?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, feats, rituals

The Ritual Caster feat provides for a character to learn and use a limited number of specifically marked spells from the spell list of another class -- for instance, a Sorcerer might take Ritual Caster and choose *find familiar* as one of the first level spells initially in the book when acquired.

The feat also specifies that the Ritual Caster may copy other ritual spells into the spell book, from the same class list they initally chose -- but what determines the *level* of the spells they may so copy and use?  Sensibly, it might be a spell level the Ritual Caster could otherwise cast, but that would close the feat from non-casting classes (like a plain Fighter) and reduce its utility for half- or quarter-caster classes (who advance spell levels very slowly compared to, say, Wizards and Clerics).

So, what level spell can my fourth-level Sorcerer put into the ritual spell book?  First only?  First and second (the level the character can cast)?  Or whatever I can find (and if so, what determines if I can *cast* those spells)?

Comment: Somewhat related (may be helpful): "[Is it possible to upcast ritual spells?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/143178)"

Comment: @Medix2 Thanks, that also raised another question, which I found to be a duplicate while typing it.  I may ask a more narrowed version, though.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The last paragraph of the Ritual Caster feat contains the sentence (emphasis added):

> The spell must be on the spell list for the class you chose, **the spell's level can be no higher than half your level (rounded up)**, and it must have the ritual tag.

So a fourth-level sorcerer can add 1st- and 2nd-level rituals to their book.

Comment: Sigh.  What I get for having these questions come to me when I'm at work, away from my gaming stuff and blocked from most gaming sites...

Comment: This answers whether a spell can be copied into a ritual book, but not whether it can then be *cast* as a ritual. A 18th level fighter could conceivably copy a Gate spell into their book; would that fighter then be able to cast Gate — a 9th level spell? (Theoretically, if that fighter had largely neglected his ritual book apart from adding Gate, their ritual casting powers might solely of 2 first level spells and 1 ninth level spell, which feel odd and counterintuitive.

Answer (score 6):

### Two things

#### Level of spells available

Per the description of the [Ritual Caster](https://www.dndbeyond.com/feats/ritual-caster) feat (PHB, p. 169; emphasis mine):

> If you come across a spell in written form, such as a magical spell scroll or a wizard's spellbook, you might be able to add it to your ritual book. The spell must be on the spell list for the class you chose, **the spell's level can be no higher than half your level (rounded up)**, and it must have the ritual tag.

Since this is a feat, it cannot be tied to any particular *class* level, so it would be based on *character* level. So your 4th-level Sorcerer can learn up to 2nd-level ritual spells.

#### Level of spell cast

When you cast a [ritual spell](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/spellcasting#Rituals), it can only be cast at its lowest level (no upcasting). Per the PHB, p. 202 (emphasis mine):

> Certain spells have a special tag: ritual. Such a spell can be cast following the normal rules for spellcasting, or the spell can be cast as a ritual. The ritual version of a spell takes 10 minutes longer to cast than normal. It also doesn't expend a spell slot, which means **the ritual version of a spell can't be cast at a higher level**.

Comment: "Since this is a feat, it cannot be tied to any particular class level, so it would be based on character level. So your 4th-level Sorcerer can learn up to 2nd-level ritual spells."

There is no evidence that feats are required to be tied to overall character level.

Comment: @SethR.Feldman, actually there is; the [Tough](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/phb/customization-options#Tough) feat. It says that when you take the feat it changes your hit point max based on **level** not class level. Also remember, Variant Human can take a Feat just by being a Human. There would be no class level to tie it to.